# Freeing with 12 capacity Log message in Oppo device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I got 10000+ log messages within five seconds in the debug console in android studio and also terminal using Oppo device. How do I stop this log message?

```
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 12 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 12 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 6 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 6 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 60 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 12 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 12 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 12 capacity
D/Parcel  (18925): Parcel 0x79ad9cc150: freeing with 12 capacity
```

Comment: most devices spit out alot of garbage logs, so you can either read only your own logs and suppress others with `adb logcat MyLog:v *:s` or just make a certain tag shut up with `adb logcat Parcel:s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's Problem of Device i connected.

Some oppo devices was showing that logs.